# JQuery timer not working properly in second time button click after finishing first attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Count down timer . I am using the following functions :
`setInterval` and `clearInterval`. Please check my fiddle

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/yw921so3/6/)

In first button click it works fine. When timer reaches zero and I am click again, then it not working correctly. Timer not decreased with 1sec interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setInterval()`is declared inside a function, so it cannot be reached from another function. That means your `clearInterval()` doesn't find `counter`.

To make it works, you have to declare `counter`outside the `clickme()` function :

```
var counter;
function clickme(){
    count = 10;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quLnykya/)

Comment: Thank you buddy. It is working. Thanks for the quick reply!!

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped :)